# CentOS7 - Upgrade Docker to latest Version without losing running containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos7

I am working on a centOS environment and I have configured kubectl using kubeadm to work with k8s and learn about it. I have configured it using containerd as I am working with k8s v1.26.2.

The problem is that I am not able to configure the coredns pod when executing kubeadm init as you can see here:

```
[root@portov7 config_files]# kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE      NAME                                              READY   STATUS                  RESTARTS   AGE
default        podtest                                           0/1     ContainerCreating       0          130m
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-hqh9z                             0/1     Init:ImagePullBackOff   0          55m
kube-system    coredns-787d4945fb-2msm9                          0/1     ContainerCreating       0          154m
kube-system    coredns-787d4945fb-hms2c                          0/1     ContainerCreating       0          154m
kube-system    etcd-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net                      1/1     Running                 0          154m
kube-system    kube-apiserver-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net            1/1     Running                 0          154m
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net   1/1     Running                 0          154m
kube-system    kube-proxy-7r7nz                                  1/1     Running                 0          154m
kube-system    kube-scheduler-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net            1/1     Running                 0          154m
```

Seems that the problem is related to the flannel plugin that is not being found on the /opt/cni/bin directory. I have found that this plugin is not used anymore and I am thinking that maybe the problem is related to mu docker version(correct me if I am wrong please).

also, the problem here is that I have some docker containers running in parallel and I would like to migrate them to the latest docker version (currently I am using 1.13.1 version).

So I have two questions here:

- Is the flannel error generated by the docker version incompatibility somehow? I already created the 10-**flannel.conflist** flannel file but seems is not working.
- If the docker version is the problem, the only way to migrate is by using the volumes to save the data and delete and recreate again the containers?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the **code, logs, output, error messages... in the question body as code blocks**. Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and is specifically listed as a bad practice in [ask]. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already fixed it by performing the download and installation of the https://github.com/coreos/flannel/raw/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml file.

After the download I executed the command kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml and the flannel was configured and the coredns pods are running.

I had to add the `imagePullPolicy: Never` to the images after imported them to the CRI by using the `ctr` command.

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-flannel   kube-flannel-ds-lx6cn                             1/1     Running   0          9s
kube-system    coredns-787d4945fb-5rjbv                          1/1     Running   0          27m
kube-system    coredns-787d4945fb-jqs5w                          1/1     Running   0          27m
kube-system    etcd-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net                      1/1     Running   2          27m
kube-system    kube-apiserver-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net            1/1     Running   2          27m
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net   1/1     Running   2          27m
kube-system    kube-proxy-mkrwd                                  1/1     Running   0          27m
kube-system    kube-scheduler-portov7.gre.hpecorp.net            1/1     Running   2          27m
```